# Redis bitwise operator in index filter

Tags: filter, redis, bit-manipulation

I am new to redis and I am struggling to find the way to filter by 1 specific bit in an indexed numeric field (an int):

I am storing serialized json objects that contain a @mask property which is basically an integer that encodes a set of values(kind of encoding a set: bit 1 means that the first item in the set is present, the second bit means that it includes the second value of the set and so forth). Therefore if a given objects contains the 1 and 3rd item the set, the value would be 9. There are 35 different items in the set.

I also have of course an index (on JSON)covering this and other fields, my question is, how can I specify a filter for that index that returns only the objects wit the 3rd value? in logical terms it would be something like @mask && 8 == 8, and it would cover the value 8, but also 9, 10, 11, etc (but not 17). Keep in mind that the filter can include multiple fields, this one being one of them.

I hope the question is clear enough ...

I tried using && in the search filter, but its not allowed, Also looked at SETs and BITOP, but they dont seem to be applicable in the filter (or I dont know how to apply them). I also thought of applying closed ranges i.e. [8 8], but that does not work with so many values.

Note: I had this working with an array of tags, however I want to save memory by not storing the whole serialized array in redis.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but alas, RediSearch doesn't do that. Closed ranges could work, but, like you said, there would be too many of them. I think a TAG array is you best bet.

Comment: Probably less efficient than TAGs and less general, but if you can translate your bit check into arithmetic one (e.g `x&1` is the same as `x%2==1`) you can use `FILTER`